# Explicit expression for root of equation

Tags: roots, lambert-w

Is it possible to find an explicit expression for the root(s) (except $x=0$) for the following function

$$f(x)= x-2 + 2b^x$$

where $0\leq b \leq 1$. Numerically this is no problem at all. But what about an explicit expression? I suppose this is an transcendental equation?

**EDIT**:
Thanks to   Gerry Myerson, I learned that the answer is given by the Lambert W function, i.e. roots of $f$, denoted $\gamma$ are given by

$$\gamma = 2- \frac{W_k(2b^2 \log{b})}{\log{b}}$$

where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$  and $W_k$ is the $k$'th branch of the Lambert W function.

**Related question:**

I numerically observed that the $k=0$ branch has maximal real part for a range of $k$'s. Can this be right and be proven by simple properties?

Comment: Read up on the Lambert W function.

Comment: For your related question, yes, that's basically the definition of the $k=0$ branch.  Read the paper by Corless et. al. in which the branches are discussed: [pdf link](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf)

Comment: @AntonioVargas, thanks for the paper suggestion. Still I don't understand why $Re(W_0(x)) \geq Re(W_k(x))$ for all $x\in [-1/e, 0]$...

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested, I can still solve this:

$$0=x-2+2b^x$$

Use substitution $x-2=A$.

$$0=A+2b^{A+2}=A+2b^2b^A$$

$$A=-2b^2b^A=-2b^2e^{\ln(b)A}$$

$$1=-2b^2A^{-1}e^{\ln(b)A}$$

$$1=-\frac12b^{-2}Ae^{-\ln(b)A}$$

Substitute $-\frac12b^{-2}=X$

$$1=XAe^{-\ln(b)A}$$

$$X^{-1}=Ae^{-\ln(b)A}$$

$$-X^{-1}\ln(b)=-\ln(b)Ae^{-\ln(b)A}$$

$$-\ln(b)A=W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))$$

$$A=\frac{W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))}{-\ln(b)}=X^{-1}e^{W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))}$$

$$A=-2b^2e^{W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))}$$

$$x-2=-2b^2e^{W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))}$$

$$x=-2b^2e^{W(-X^{-1}\ln(b))}+2$$

Comment: I simply prefer to have my answer in $e^{W(f)}$ form.  Also note that you can still have the $k$ branches of $W$.